# выполнение баш скрипта в jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, devops, jenkins-pipeline

Хочу сделать пайп который будет запускать разные баш скрипты на разных нодах Jenkins. Но не могу понять как засунуть в пайп выполнение не одной команды, а целого скрипта. Еще хочу передавать параметры из сборки, если можете подсказать где почитать - буду очень благодарен. Вот пример пайпа 
pipeline {
   agent any

stages {

```
  stage('drop_user') {
      agent{ label 'linux'}

     steps {
         //echo ${user2}
        //echo "ansible"
        bash ''' 
         #!/bin/bash

        get_host=''

        for server in $dbserver
        do
        echo "check if exist user"

        test_user="$(mysql  -h ${server} -u ${user_mysql} -p${password} -sse "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '${user2}')")"

        if [ "$test_user" = 1 ]; then
                echo "user exist on ${server}"

                get_host=`mysql -h ${server} -u ${user_mysql} -p${password} -e "select host from mysql.user where user = '${user2}';"`



                host='0'
                for i in $get_host
                do

                        host=$i
                done


                mysql -h ${server} -u ${user_mysql} -ppassword -e "drop user  '${user2}'@'$host';"
                echo "user ${user2} is drop on ${server}"
        else
                echo "user doesn't exist"
        fi
        done"
        '''
     }

  }
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

нашел ответ в конструкторе http://jenkins:8080/pipeline-syntax/
там же нашел тему про параметры сборки